# concat using a blank space as separator marks questions instead of blank space

Tags: t-sql, concatenation

This query

```
SELECT  Empleados.U_Sociedad as Sociedad, 
    Empleados.empID AS empId, 
    CONCAT(Empleados.firstName , ' ' , Empleados.middleName , ' ' , Empleados.lastName)  as Nombre,
    sum(
        case 
            when durtype = 'm' 
            then duration/ 60 
            else duration 
        end
        ) as Realizado ,
    0 as Planificado,
    'Horas' as Concepto 
FROM OHEM Empleados   
JOIN OUSR Usuarios ON Empleados.U_CODEMPL = Usuarios.USER_CODE   
JOIN OCLG Horas ON Usuarios.INTERNAL_K = Horas.AttendUser   
WHERE(Horas.U_Fase ='w0000005') 
group by U_Sociedad, empID ,CONCAT(Empleados.firstName , ' ' , Empleados.middleName , ' ' , Empleados.lastName)
```

Shows this
[image: result]

I don't understand Why the ' ' is translated to '?'

Amy idea Please?

regards

Comment: Is this from SQL Server Management Studio?  Usually something like this is because your client does not know how to render the character and it gets replaced with some other default character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The spaces you posted in your example are CHAR(63)'s not real spaces: CHAR(32).

I copy/pasted the spaces directly from your post. Note that this: `SELECT ASCII(' ')`
Retutns 63. I copied the spaces into CONCAT like this: `SELECT CONCAT('a', ' ' , 'a', ' ' , 'x');` 
returns: a?a?x

You can explicitly specify `CHAR(32)` spaces like so:

```
SELECT CONCAT('a', CHAR(32) , 'b', CHAR(32), 'c');
```

Or, to avoid having to type CHAR(32) over and over, you can do this:

```
SELECT CONCAT('a',Sp,'b',Sp, 'c')
FROM (VALUES(CHAR(32))) AS s(Sp);
```

OR, if you SQL Server 2017+ you can use CONCAT_WS like so:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(CHAR(32),'a','b','c');
```